# Betterposter: Put some space between rows in the Title

Tags: spacing, titles, posters

I am using the Betterposter (https://github.com/rafaelbailo/betterposter-latex-template) class for a poster in LaTeX but  my problem comes because my title is really long.

I was wondering how I can create some space between the rows of the text so that the output does not look jumbled up.

This is the title command in the .cls file

```
%% Title command
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{
{\fontsizetitle\textbf{\leavevmode
#1
}}\\

}
```

`\fontsizetitle` is

```
\renewcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{56.57}{70.71} \selectfont}
```

and my title is

```
\title{May God's Grace Guide My Vote: How Subliminal Primes of Place Influence Voter Decision Making}
```

The output is
[image]

How can I increase the spacing (even if it is ever so slightly) between the rows in the title line? I am not looking for a double spacing of the text, only a few points in between the lines.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to add manual linebreaks with an optional vertical space argument, i.e., `\\[space]`, for example `\\[10mm]`. You didn't specify the size of your poster, but with A0 (the default) I had to set the font size to 72pt to fit the last two words on a single line (*Decision Making*).

MWE:

```
%%%% Better Poster latex template example v1.0 (2019/04/04)
%%%% GNU General Public License v3.0
%%%% Rafael Bailo
%%%% https://github.com/rafaelbailo/betterposter-latex-template
%%%% 
%%%% Original design from Mike Morrison
%%%% https://twitter.com/mikemorrison
\documentclass[a0paper,fleqn]{betterposter}
\begin{document}    
\betterposter{
%%%%%%%% CENTER COLUMN
  \maincolumn{
    \textbf{Main finding} goes here,
  }{
  }
}{
%%%%%%%% LEFT COLUMN
\renewcommand{\fontsizetitle}{\fontsize{72}{90} \selectfont}
\title{May God's Grace\\[10mm] Guide My Vote:\\[10mm] How Subliminal\\[10mm] Primes of Place\\[10mm] Influence Voter\\[10mm] Decision Making}
\author{Mike Morrison}
\author{Rafael Bailo}
\institution{Optional Institution Under Name}
}{
%%%%%%%% RIGHT COLUMN
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that, because of the manual line breaks, the title is not justified. If you want that, then you can put a minipage in the title (which is justified by default), and set the distance between lines automatically using the second argument of the `\fontsize` command. It would be expected that this is also possible without a minipage but for some reason the line distance does not change when using this command without a minipage. This solution requires that you set the width of the title manually, here I have used `0.8\leftbarwidth`, where `\leftbarwidth` is defined by the class to be `0.2\paperwidth` and the 0.8 adjusts for the margins.

MWE:

```
%%%% Better Poster latex template example v1.0 (2019/04/04)
%%%% GNU General Public License v3.0
%%%% Rafael Bailo
%%%% https://github.com/rafaelbailo/betterposter-latex-template
%%%% 
%%%% Original design from Mike Morrison
%%%% https://twitter.com/mikemorrison
\documentclass[a0paper,fleqn]{betterposter}
\begin{document}    
\betterposter{
%%%%%%%% CENTER COLUMN
  \maincolumn{
    \textbf{Main finding} goes here,
  }{
  }
}{
%%%%%%%% LEFT COLUMN
\title{\begin{minipage}{0.8\leftbarwidth}%
\fontsize{72}{90} \selectfont%
May God's Grace Guide My Vote: How Subliminal Primes of Place Influence Voter Decision Making%
\end{minipage}}
\author{Mike Morrison}
\author{Rafael Bailo}
\institution{Optional Institution Under Name}
}{
%%%%%%%% RIGHT COLUMN
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]